# Why is ALTER TABLE xy ALTER COLUMN ab TYPE type not working in PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, alter

I'm using PostgreSQL with Python, although the subject matter of the current question seems to be pure SQL.

Based on the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-alter.html#id-1.5.4.7.10), changing the type of a column should be done like this:

```
ALTER TABLE products ALTER COLUMN price TYPE numeric(10,2);
```

So, if I have a table called "checks", in which there is a column "check_date_time" with the type "timestamp" and I want to change this to "timestamptz", then, based on the above, this should work:

```
ALTER TABLE checks ALTER COLUMN check_date_time TYPE timestamptz;
```

But guess what... it doesn't. I keep getting the error message

> Error executing SQL statement. ERROR: syntax error at end of input
> Position: 19 - Connection: Test: 31ms

Everything else works, by the way. I can create tables, do selects, etc., just ALTER is giving me these troubles. I've been at this for about an hour now and I'm really running out of ideas as to what issues it could have. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: It is [not reproducible](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=06b119b827a6240fc13c18dc9b2bb265). Syntax error is syntax error, do this statement (copypasted) work in Postgres via some IDE? Do you put a semicolon at the end of the statement in Python? Try to remove it.

Comment: @astentx I tried it via PyCharm's database navigator/console as well as through my program (using psycopg2) but neither approach worked. Tried it with and without the semicolon but it did not seem to make any difference, as I still got the same error message even then.

Comment: What does this statement show you `select relname, relkind
from pg_class
where lower(relname) = lower('CHECKS')`?

Comment: @astentx now that the change has already been made, it shows `checks r` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct timezone might not being applied on the conversion, if you don't explicit this, the timezone will be assumed, and typically isn't UTC.

```
ALTER TABLE checks
  ALTER check_date_time TYPE timestamptz USING check_date_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
, ALTER check_date_time SET DEFAULT now();
```

Comment: This only resulted in a different error message:

Error executing ALTER VIEW statement. ERROR: syntax error at or near "check_date_time"
  Position: 7 - Connection: Test: 21ms

Comment: @Gabriel Why `view` is present in the error message? You can alter only table's columns

Comment: @Rodrigo Feraz Souza Before, I tried this in the console. There it didn't work indeed and resulted in the error message quoted. However, I just tried to shoot it through my program and interestingly enough, there, it worked. The type of the column has been changed as needed. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @astentax Good question, I don't know. But as it seems, something probably isn't quite right with my console's settings. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Gábriel hahaha it happens sometimes, you're welcome!
Computers already have free will, and this kind of stuff proves it hahahahahah